# PHP Frameworks That Don't Use a Front Controller?

Tags: php, frameworks

Just like the title says, are there any PHP web application frameworks that don't use a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)?

> The Front Controller Pattern is a software design pattern listed in
> several pattern catalogs. The pattern relates to the design of web
> applications. It "provides a centralized entry point for handling
> requests."
>
> The front controller may be implemented as a Java
> object, or as a script in a script language like PHP, ASP, CFML or JSP
> that is called on every request of a web session. This script, for
> example an index.php, would handle all tasks that are common to the
> application or the framework, such as session handling, caching, and
> input filtering. Based on the specific request it would then
> instantiate further objects and call methods to handle the particular
> task(s) required.
>
> The alternative to a front controller would be
> individual scripts like login.php and order.php that would each then
> satisfy the type of request. Each script would have to duplicate code
> or objects that are common to all tasks. But each script might also
> have more flexibility to implement the particular task required.

Comment: As I'm writing a front controlled system, (front controlling makes a number of tasks easier) I'm quite curious about your reason for discriminating on the front controller feature. Just a matter of taste, or did you find some relevant drawbacks about them?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few without it. Like Seagoull or Rain Framework.

You can see a list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks#PHP

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework is modular. You can use only the parts you need without being forced into a front controller.

Comment: Yes, but if you're using the whole shebang (the MVC part of it) then yes, you do have to use a front controller.